# storing a fragment vs using a component in react

Tags: reactjs

In React, is there a meaningful difference between storing fragments in a variable and generating them through a component?

Example:

```
export default function App() {

  const greetingFragment = <div>Hello world!</div>;

  const GreetingComponent = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {greetingFragment}
      <GreetingComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Would it be different if the fragment had logic in it? What if the fragment grew in size, is there a point in which the best way (or expected way or "react way") is to use a component?

Or is it just a matter of "taste" and readability.

Comment: Nesting components like you've done is not a good idea, since the nested component's identity changes on each render, causing unnecessary remounts and rerenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

✅ Storing a static fragment in a module-level variable is fine:

```
const greetingFragment = <div>Hello world!</div>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {greetingFragment}
    </div>
  );
}
```

✅ Storing a static fragment in a component-level variable is fine, and can reduce long nesting in your component:

```
export default function App() {
  const greetingFragment = <div>Hello world!</div>;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {greetingFragment}
    </div>
  );
}
```

⛔ Nesting components is *not* fine since the nested component's identity changes on each render, causing unnecessary remounts and rerenders (and other weirdness):

```
export default function App() {
  const GreetingComponent = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GreetingComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

✅ Making the nested component a module-level variable is fine, and will cause a component boundary (which could be useful to avoid certain reconciliations, or to be able to use hooks within `GreetingComponent`).

This will be rendered as 2 components.

```
const GreetingComponent = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;

export default function App() { 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GreetingComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

You can (technically, though I can't recommend it unless you know what you're doing) also call a function component as a function (if it doesn't use hooks, or if you're careful about the rules of hooks). This will be rendered as 1 component.

```
const GreetingComponent = () => <div>Hello world!</div>;

export default function App() { 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {GreetingComponent()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I was looking for an explanation like that but didn't even know how to google it :D

Comment: I get that the nested component re-renders each time the parent component re-renders... but what about the fragment? Fragments don't re-render, that code is not run with each re-render of the parent? (can you tell I am a noobie? :D)

Comment: Of course React will have to look through the markup you return from your component to see if it needs to be reconciled with the real DOM, but it's a lighter re-render (contrary to the nested component case, which _always_ causes the nested component to get unmounted and remounted since it's fundamentally not the same component).

Comment: Got it! Thanks!